# Dynamically edit img src based on device orientation with JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, image, device-orientation

I am working with an iOS magazine framework (PugPig) which loads HTML documents into a WebKit powered view (a chromeless version of Mobile Safari).

I would like each 'page' to load either a portrait or landscape version of an <img/> depending on the orientation of the device. For various reasons it has to be an <img/> rather than a CSS background image, so media queries won't work. Because I am loading HTML from the local device, no web server stuff can be used either.

So I am guessing that JS is the way to go, but it would need to detect orientation change (or at least screen width) on the fly, without a page refresh, and I don't know if this is possible.

Not hugely familiar with JS hence no sample code (all my attempts so far are car crashes). Sorry.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a solution using CSS Media Queries after all, by setting the display property of the img. Bit of a fudge, but fine for now.

Basically I created two divs, one with a 'landscape' id and another with 'portrait', positioned absolutely on top of each other. Then used `@media` queries to show/hide the relevant div with the display: property. Very clumsy, not at all suitable for the web but okay for an iPad app loading data straight from memory. And this was before "responsive images" became a thing.

Comment: This was a while ago, so I don't have the code to hand. From memory: I created two divs, one with a 'landscape' id and another with 'portrait', positioned absolutely on top of each other. Then used @media queries to show/hide the relevant div with the display: property. Very clumsy, not at all suitable for the web but okay for an iPad app loading data straight from memory. And this was before "responsive images" became a thing...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `jQuery mobile`'s `orientationchange` [events](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/events.html)?

I've never done this, but it seems you could go this way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, will respond.

Comment: Thanks bububaba, but found a different solution. Sure I will need JQuery Mobile and what it can offer soon though!